# Capturing response body in Express Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to write a small API logger as an Express middleware. The logger collects various pieces of information from the req and res, then saves a JSON file to disk that can be read later.

This is my current function to store the logs.

```
function store(req, res, next) {
  init();

  const log = {
    request_url: req.hostname,
    request_body: req.body,
    request_method: req.method,
    request_headers: req.headers,
    api_endpoint: req.baseUrl,
    timestamp: moment().format('x')
  };

  res.on('finish', () => {
    log.response_body = res.body;
    log.response_status = res.statusCode;

    global.enoch_logs.push(log);

    fs.writeFile(`./logs/${ moment().format('x') }.json`, JSON.stringify(log), (err) => (err) ? console.log(err) : null);
  });

  next();
}
```

The problem is that res.body is always empty. I have tried a few different methods to capture the response body but nothing seems to work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: res does not have a body property https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: Hmm, so I see. How would I go about getting the response then when the response is sent?

Comment: There are various packages that you could use, or take a look at: [`express-interceptor`](https://github.com/axiomzen/express-interceptor), [`morgan-body`](https://github.com/sirrodgepodge/morgan-body), [`express-mung`](https://github.com/richardschneider/express-mung).

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the body-parser.
eg. import bodyParser from "body-parser";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).